# Google map jagged on marker select

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hello I am new with jQuery & Google Map API and I have some question so I hope I will get answer :)

I am using this Google Map for my project: [JSFiddle](http://goo.gl/zt9YjF) but I am getting two issues.

1. I am not able to set default zoom level. I have tried to change zoom: 5 but not worked for me.
2. When user click to any marker smooth transition not working when marker is moving to center. Check another example which I am referring http://marcgrabanski.com/resources/jquery-google-maps/tutorial-part1.html

I will appreciate if you provide me JSFiddle :)

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question, not just a link to a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your default zoom level is 5 but you are using `map.fitBounds(bounds);` which set different zoom level according to bounds:

```
function AutoCenter() {
    //  Create a new viewpoint bound
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    //  Go through each...
    $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
        bounds.extend(marker.position);
    });
    //  Fit these bounds to the map
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

So you have to comment out call to `AutoCenter()` or `map.fitBounds(bounds);`.

Smooth transition: that example uses Google APIS v2. You can get better transition using `map.panTo()` instead of `map.setCenter()` function. See [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3Lft/1/).

Comment: Have you changed anything for my question number 2?

Comment: `map.panTo()`: *Changes the center of the map to the given LatLng. If the change is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated.*